# Is it possible to align inputs/labels in multiple inline forms?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap 3 and I stuck on some form formatting.

E.g. I want to have 3 inline forms (each with label, text input and button) so they elements (label, text input, button) will be all perfectly matching (in column?)

If you look at [this fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/yft9w47u/) you can see, that I almost achieved this by setting `col-xs-6` to each form-group. But this makes too big space between input and submit button and also break too soon when resizing (and also when I try to align whole form set to left, everything is broken).

So is there any way to align this form elements instead of this?

```
  <form class="form-inline">
      <div class="form-group col-xs-6 text-right">
        <label for="exampleInputName2">Results per page</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName2" >
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
      </div>
    </form>

    <form class="form-inline">
      <div class="form-group col-xs-6 text-right">
        <label for="exampleInputName2">Keyword weight</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName2" >
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
      </div>
    </form>

    <form class="form-inline">
      <div class="form-group col-xs-6 text-right">
        <label for="exampleInputName2">Results per page</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName2" >
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just give a width to your `label`?  If you put the three elements into the same column then you can just make the label inline-block and give it a width (you may need to use the full page link in the snippet below to see this working)

```css
.form-group > label {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 9em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputName2">Results per page</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName2">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
  </div>
</form>

<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputName2">Keyword weight</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName2">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
  </div>
</form>

<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputName2">Results per page</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName2">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

This [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/magician03/ytckmnob/1/) might help you. The entire layout can be put into container and each form can be given a `margin` and `text-align` css properties.

And I dont think there is a need for `text-right` and `col-xs-6` to be included, instead you can use `container` to restrict the `max-width` and make it more responsive as shown in the fiddle.

Comment: But when you try lenght of label, so one or more will be longer than other, you will see as the layout broke :(

Comment: You can use something like `max-width` to fix broken layout, but I cant find it anywhere in the fiddle, anyways, you can the `max-width` property to fix the width of form or text-input field, when anything breaks the layout